# Paramater-based dependecies and outs in DVC from constants file

Tags: python, dvc

I am trying to define a single-source set of paths such that it can be modified if necessary from a single spot rather than modifying it in various places across many scripts. I am doing this by simply using a `constants.py` file:

*constants.py*

```py
MY_DATA="data/location"
MY_OUT="data/out"
```

I tried doing it by using the top-level `vars` declaration in my `dvc.yaml` but to no avail:

*dvc.yaml*

```yaml
vars:
  - constants.py

stages:
  something:
    deps:
      - ${MY_DATA}
    outs:
      - ${MY_OUT}
    cmd: python some_script.py
```

What is the proper way to do this in DVC? I looked at `params` too but I'm not sure whether that fits this specific use case or whether it'd be valid.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax looks correct and works for me when I try it. If you are still having trouble, you can open an issue in https://github.com/iterative/dvc.